# Paste numbers as string in google docs

Tags: google-docs

I have one spreadsheet of google docs with data like :

```
0012
0234
0065
```

i wanna paste in another google doc spreadsheet but with ctrl+c ctrl+v format data like numbers :

```
12
234
65
```

And i want conserve the string format. 
With rigth-click copy-paste i cant copy.
Tested in firefox and chromium.

Edit: i have hundreds of rows, edit mannually not is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a single quote (`'`) in front of the zeros before you copy the cells.

If you need to apply this to lots of cells, set the contents of one cell to `'` and use `CONCAT` to populate a new column with the `'` and the cell contents.

If A1 is `'` and the values you want to copy start in B1:

Set C1 to `=CONCAT($A$1, $B1)` and fill the formula down.

Comment: @AndrésRicardoTorresMartínez You should be able to do this pretty easily using `CONCAT` to concatenate the `'` with the cell contents you need into a new column.